# ssis packages modifying files under source control

Tags: tfs, ssis

This is more of a hypothetical question as I am sure this is not a very good way to do things.

Say I have an SSIS package, under source control in TFS, that needs to read and modify some files, say a csv. how does it handle modifying the csv if the csv is also under source control in TFS?

i don't have a complete understanding of how it works, but i assume the csv would be under write protection until it is checked out. Does the ssis package just error out when attempting to write to a write protected file? Having to modify the SSIS packages to somehow get around the write protection would require a lot of work as all the these packages are already written and being added to source control now. alternatively, I assume there is some kind of settings you can do in TFS to turn off write protection on your local copy or automatically check out a file if it is being modified.

is the real solution to just keep the input and output files from the SSIS package outside of source control (as there is probably questionable justification for them to be there in the first place?)

Comment: I think you hit the answer with your final question.  If we're using SSIS to dynamically move data into text files, there are all sorts of archiving mechanisms available to preserve those files outside of adding them to source control.

Answer (score 0):

TFS is integrated into Visual Studio. When you edit a package, VS checks it out of TFS for you and you can use Visual Studio's interface to check it back in.

In VS, Tools/Options/Source Control sets up the source control provider. File/Source Control is where you manage the connection to the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your workspace over to a local workspace the read only attribute is removed for all files.

If however you need to edit the file in a normal workspace why I'd it under source control at all? A better way would to have separate files for DataIn, DataOut, and DataCompare. You should have DatIn and DataCompare under source control, but DataOut should be generated.

It is not recommended to have any generated files under source control.